# "'value >= min && value <=max' : is not true " Even though value is in-between :: Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

This is my first app and also I am posting for the first time here. Sorry if there are any mistakes.

I made a sorting visualization app, in which you can change the size of array through a slider.
It was working totally fine until sometime ago after i made few changes (unrelated to the slider) and then I started getting this error.

Hot and cold restart aren't working.

Also I tried reverting to the previous version (which was working totally fine)

I am attaching the parts of code and error screenshots.

```
double totalBars = 15.0;
```

[Declaring the variable as 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc7rg.png)

```
Slider(
                      label: '${totalBars.toInt()}',
                      value: totalBars,
                      onChanged: isSorting
                          ? null
                          : (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                totalBars = val;
                                _buildArray();
                              });
                            },
                      activeColor: getcolor(),
                      inactiveColor: kbuttonbackgnd,
                      max: 20.0,
                      min: 10.0,
                      divisions: 10,
                    ),
```

[min and max values set as 10 and 20 respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqnJL.png)

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building BruteForce(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: 
BruteForceState#b1381):
'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 132 pos 15: 'value >= min && value 
<= max': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
BruteForce 
file:///C:/Users/Arnav%20Shindolkar/AndroidStudioProjects/algolizzzer/lib/Screens/menu.dart:45:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Slider (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:132:15)
#3      BruteForceState.build (package:algolizzzer/Screens/BruteForce.dart:785:32)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iln75.png)

Comment: what do see if you add `print(totalBars);` in the first line of `BruteForceState.build` method?

Comment: @pskink ohh The app now works if I change max to greater than the printed totalBars valueI did this and it's printing 200 something for some reason! why is that so?

Comment: i cant see your whole code, so...

Comment: Why is the totalBars value not 15?

Comment: because you set it somewhere to `200` something